# Rub marks in paint

Tags: paint

I was removing dead bugs from my car, they were so bad the car wash and pressure cleaner could not rid them.  I used a light compound on them and they are now gone but now I see every mark on the car from where I rubbed.  How do I get my car looking new again?  I should have looked up how to remove these before I used compound.

Thanks!

Comment: You need the proper clear coat polish...https://www.startpage.com/do/dsearch?query=clear+coat+polish&cat=web&pl=opensearch&language=english

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Best first treatment for dead bugs is a wet rag, placed over the bugs to hydrate them and left in place for, perhaps, several hours.